# JQuery datepicker icon trigger broken after inserting data to database

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter, jquery-ui-datepicker

at first i got to load my icon for the JQuery datepicker but after i insert the value to my database the icon image is broken. im using Codeigniter framework.

here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">    
     <title>CRUD</title>
<?php echo link_tag(base_url() . 'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css'); ?>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <?php
    echo form_label('BDay:', 'bday');

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'bday',
        'id' => 'datepicker'
    ); 

    echo form_input($data);
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my jscript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "<?php echo base_url() . '/images/icons/calendar_24.png' ?>",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
            $("input[name='bday']").val(dateText);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

am i missing something? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the head - You aren't adding jQuery or jQuery ui to your project

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh! i forgot to include it in my post. im so sorry, but i already have that code in my head tag, still not working.

Comment: @crisginecallano Can you create a jsfiddle.net?  and show us what's not working?  It makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot